# ADAL-Angular offline support (am I missing something?)

Tags: angularjs, adal

I have seen what looks to be a nice way to handle offline mode for adal but its based on attaching to the displayCall and then accessing the Context.. unfortunately context isn't exposed in the Angular wrapper. Before I go write something custom around ADAL directly, I figured I would ask how others have handled AppCache based offline applications with ADAL? My use case is spotty internet access via mobile devices in rural areas. Online I want the users to go through the ADAL flow (which works great). Offline I want them to validate they have access to the local cache of data via a locally hashed pin.

Thoughts?
Thanks all.

Comment: Can you expand more on the local cache storage?

Comment: So local cache would be what ever activity the user is doing offline, encrypt the local storage with the users "pin" and then store a hash of the pin for offline authentication... From an ADAL perspective I just want to know if there is a way to "fake it out" regarding the user logged in and such when its online... I have read some stuff around using displayCall.. However, that only works if you have the context, which you don't have access to in angular via the adal-angular module.

Comment: Still having a little bit of an issue understanding, but I can speak to displayCall.  Using the displayCall hands over control to the app when you call login() before redirecting and firing an auth request.  Basically, you'll provide a callback, and ADAL.js will do it's thing and stop right before starting the request and will pass your app the constructed auth URL.  Your app can then modify/append/delete any piece of this and then finish the request by hand.  [Checkout this github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/462) for code steps to configure.

Comment: If you are still not sure how to accomplish this, go ahead and open an issue on github describing the general scenario & that you're not sure how to use displayCall!

Comment: The issue at its root is that the adalcontext is a hidden variable in the adalAuthenticationService so I can't replicate adal's behavior if I construct my own displayCall.. (I can't call promptUser or _loginPopup)...  I'll file a request/issue for the context to be exposed so that calls to promptUser or _loginPopup are available to angular environments.

Comment: placing the configuration of displayCall in the config pipeline is actually quite problematic... I am working through the difficulties now but you have no access to the UI in config, so writing a callback method with no way to inject or call other services is a touch challenging.. (to say the lease ;-).. )

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in ADAL.js intended to support offline scenarios.

ADAL is used to get an access token in the connected case for a Web API.  It has no mechanism to secure a local datastore/cache with a token.

Comment: I know it doesn't understand local cache.. I guess my question wasn't clear enough.. I was wondering if there is a way to "override" its behavior when the browser is offline so that I can manually (via my own process) mark the user as logged in... Ignore the local cache side of the story..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the right answer is to definitely use config.displayCall.. However displayCall is configured during app.config with adal-angular, which pretty much makes it impossible to really use in angular.. So here are a few code tweaks you can add to adal-angular so that you too can take control (if you need to)..

1) add the following var/function in your provider (I did it around line 48)

```
var internalDisplayCall = function (url) {
                if (userDefinedDisplayCall) {
                    userDefinedDisplayCall(url);
                } else {
                    if (_adal.popUp) {
                        _adal._loginPopup(url);
                    }
                    else {
                        _adal.promptUser(url);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Thats pretty much the same logic as what is in adal regarding if there is a displayCall method or not.

2) add a var for userDefinedDisplayCall around the same area

```
  var userDefinedDisplayCall = undefined;
```

3) you will need the context because there is no "fall through" behavior to displayCall to use default behavior in adal (or in my copy of how adal behaves) so add that to your provider in the returned object. (I did this around line 390)

```
context: _adal,
```

4) add a method to set userDefinedDisplayCall method and add THAT to your return object as well.. I did that inline in the return object, so again around line 390

```
setDisplayCall: function (newDisplayCall) {
                        if (newDisplayCall && typeof newDisplayCall !== 'function') {
                            throw new Error('displayCall is not a function');
                        }
                        userDefinedDisplayCall = newDisplayCall;
                    }
```

Right now you can configure your adalServiceProvider in app.config with your azure AD tenant, your appId, and all that required jazz, then you can inject adalService in app.run and configure the displayCall so you can inject your own behaviors...